# Scrapy Response is returning 'None' even with correct syntax

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to get the item's names in a dictionary like this:

```
import scrapy


class TerrorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'terror'
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/travel_2/index.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        for filme in response.css('h3 a'):
           yield{
            'name': filme.css('h3 a::text').get()
           }
```

And i really don't know why it's returning 'None' in 'name' field (it's returning code 200). When i try to get it on Scrapy Shell, it's works.

I'm expecting to get datas like this other code:

```
import scrapy


class ImdbSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'imdb'
    start_urls = ['https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250']

    def parse(self, response):
        for filmes in response.css('.titleColumn'):
            yield{
                'names' : filmes.css('.titleColumn a::text').get(),
                'years' : filmes.css('.secondaryInfo ::text').get()[1:-1],
                'notes' : response.css('strong ::text').get() 
            }
```

it's works correctly and is the same code.

Comment: The second code is not the same code as the first code, I don't know why you think that.

Comment: is the same principle, with different sites

Comment: So apparently the second site has `filmes.css('.titleColumn a::text')` and the first site doesn't have `filme.css('h3 a::text')`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the selector for the selector you have already chosen... In other words all you need to do is call `.css('::text').get()` on the fileme variables.  There is no need to repeat the `h3` and `a` tag elements because you already chose those in the earlier selector.

```
import scrapy


class TerrorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'terror'
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/travel_2/index.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        for filme in response.css('h3 a'):
           yield{
            'name': filme.css('::text').get()
           }
```

you could also do:

```
...

def parse(self, response):
    for filme in response.css('h3 a::text').getall():
        yield {'name': fileme}
```

or even:

```
def parse(self, response): yield from ({'name': fileme} for fileme in response.css('a h3::text').getall())
```